# replace strings of one row if one of the columns has specific string

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame like below:

```
s1 AA AG AG GG AA
s2 DI DD GG GG GG
S3 TT CC TC TT TC
S3 AA DI AA AA AA
S3 CC CC DD CC CC
```

and I want to replace all other strings to II in the row, if there is DI or DD in the row. 
so final dataframe should be like this.

```
s1 AA AG AG GG AA
s2 DI DD II II II
S3 TT CC TC TT TC
S3 II DI II II II
S4 II II DD II II
```

Any suggestions is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check both values by [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and then replace only rows with at least one `True` with [`DataFrame.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html):

```
m = df.isin(['DI','DD'])
m1 = m.any(1)
df[m1] = df[m1].where(m, 'II')
```

Or use numpy broadcasting for chain both masks:

```
m = df.isin(['DI','DD'])

df = df.where(m.values | ~m.any(1).values[:, None], 'II')
```

---

```
print (df)
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  s1  AA  AG  AG  GG  AA
1  II  DI  DD  II  II  II
2  S3  TT  CC  TC  TT  TC
3  II  II  DI  II  II  II
4  II  II  II  DD  II  II
```

EDIT:

Working with `-` is possible by chained mask by `|` for bitwise OR:

```
print (df)
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  s1  AA  AG  AG  GG   -
1  s2  DI  DD  GG  GG   -
2  S3  TT  CC  TC  TT  TC
3  S3  AA  DI  AA  AA  AA
4  S3  CC  CC  DD  CC  CC

m = df.isin(['DI','DD'])
m1 = m.any(1)
df[m1] = df[m1].where(m | df.eq('-'), 'II')
print (df)
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0  s1  AA  AG  AG  GG   -
1  II  DI  DD  II  II   -
2  S3  TT  CC  TC  TT  TC
3  II  II  DI  II  II  II
4  II  II  II  DD  II  II
```

Comment: What if there is  "--" in one of the columns of the row which has DD or DI, " and we don't want to replace it with II?

Comment: @jamo - Do you think add this value to `m = df.isin(['DI','DD', '-'])` ?

Comment: actually if the row is like this: DI DD GG -- GG, so we need to have row like : DI DD II -- II, means in that specific row shouldn't change --, can you please exclude "--" for where(m, 'II')

Comment: @jamo - There are 2 possible understanding problem  `-` are processing like `DI` or `DD` or like another values. It means if in first row is one `-` then all values without `-` are `II` ? Or whats happen?

Comment: @jezreal = you can assume "--" as NA data, we have three type of data in that specific row, [ DD/DI, -- , GG/CC/TT/AA] ; so we don't want to replace NA with II, but replace [GG/CC/TT/AA]  in the row to II.

Comment: @jamo - Can you test `m = df.replace('-', np.nan).isin(['DI','DD'])` ?

Comment: @jezreal - it didn't work. how can specify AA/CC/GG/TT instead of "any" for m?

Comment: @jezreal - Awesome, perfect.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
m = df.isin(['DI','DD']).sum(axis=1).astype(bool)

df.loc[m,:] = df.loc[m,:].applymap(lambda x: x if x in ["DI","DD"] else "II")
print(df)
```